# Attempting to plot a graph

Tags: python

Not quite sure, what the problem is I am following along with a course and the instructor's code worked perfectly fine.I am getting the `raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (5,) and (4,)` error.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x_days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_price1 = [9, 9.5, 10.1, 12]
y_price2 = [11, 12, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5]

plt.title("Stock Movement")
plt.xlabel("Week Days")
plt.ylabel("Price in USD")

plt.plot(x_days, y_price1, label="Stock 1")
plt.plot(x_days, y_price2, label="Stock 2")
plt.legend(loc=2, fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Comment: My (old school) advice would be to put some hard(er) work in and dig, and do some (more) research to get to the bottom of the issue you’re having.  Chances are, you’ll learn more in the process and improve your research and programming skills, then if I just give you the answer.  All the best!  (Experience says you’ll thank yourself later).  :-)

Answer (score 1):

your `y_price1` has 4 elements while your `x_days` has 5 elements.